# How to redraw (update) a GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am writing a chess program, and I am in the step of creating the GUI part of the chess.

To do this

I made a BoardGUI class and a TileGUI class.

The BoardGUI initializes a GridLayout -> loops through the entire grid -> initializes a TileGUI object on each grid.

The TileGUI basically gets the information of the gameBoard -> paints the tile based on its position (either dark or light color) -> draws the Piece as and add it as a JLabel object.

This basically initialized my chessboard GUI (Code written below).

On my JLabel, I am doing a small test of moving the piece to a hard-coded location whenever it is clicked (MouseListener).

It does not give me an error which means it has internally moved to that location successfully (using my back-end piece move function)

But I am not sure how to re-draw the board to update the board status.

Do I have to repeat the procedure of what the constructor of my boardPanel has (just repeating the step of initializing the board with the updated chessBoard)?

```
private class BoardGUI extends JPanel {

        BoardGUI() {

            super(new GridLayout(NUM_OF_ROWS, NUM_OF_COLS)); //Place tile on each 

            for(int row = 0; row < NUM_OF_ROWS; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < NUM_OF_COLS; col++) {
                    TileGUI tilePanel = new TileGUI(this, new Point(row, col));
                    add(tilePanel);
                }
            }

            // Invoked when container's subcomponents are modified (added or removed from the container)
            validate();
        }
    }
```

And TileGUI

```
private class TileGUI extends JPanel {

        private Point tileCoord;

        TileGUI(final BoardGUI boardPanel, final Point position) {

            super(new GridLayout());
            this.tileCoord = position;

            paintTile();

            placePieceGraphic(boardSetting);
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, boardSetting[position.x][position.y].getClass().getSimpleName());

                board.movePieceTo(boardSetting, 4, 4, boardSetting[position.x][position.y]);
                validate();

            }


            validate();

        }


        private void placePieceGraphic(Piece[][] boardSetting) {

            // Adds an empty JButton when the tile is empty
            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] == null) {
                JButton pieceButton = new JButton();

                pieceButton.setOpaque(false);
                pieceButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                pieceButton.setBorderPainted(false);
                add(pieceButton);

                pieceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "empty tile");
                    }
                });

            }

            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] != null) {

                // Retrieves the first letter of the class name

                // Retrieves the team name: UP or DOWN

                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(filename + ".png"));
                    JButton pieceButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(image));

                    add(pieceButton);
                    pieceButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            highlightValidMovement(getMovablePositions(boardSetting, tileCoord.x, tileCoord.y));   // This tries to highlight the movable tiles

                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


        private void paintTile() {

            boolean isBrightTile = (this.tileCoord.x % 2) == (this.tileCoord.y % 2);
            boolean isDarkTile = (this.tileCoord.x % 2) != (this.tileCoord.y % 2);

            if(isBrightTile) setBackground(darkColor);
            if(isDarkTile) setBackground(brightColor);


        }

    }
```

Codes that are not important is hidden.

mouseClicked is the event that handles the Piece moving.

EDIT :

```
private class TileGUI extends JPanel {

        private Point tileCoord;

        TileGUI(final BoardGUI boardPanel, final Point position) {

            super(new GridLayout());
            this.tileCoord = position;

            paintTile();

            placePieceGraphic(boardSetting);

            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, boardSetting[position.x][position.y].getClass().getSimpleName());

                    board.movePieceTo(boardSetting, 4, 4, boardSetting[position.x][position.y]);
                    placePieceGraphic(boardSetting);

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

            // Invoked when container's subcomponents are modified (added or removed from the container)

            validate();


        }
```

placePieceGraphic :

```
private void placePieceGraphic(Piece[][] boardSetting) {

            removeAll();
            // Adds an empty JButton when the tile is empty
            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] == null) {
                JLabel pieceLabel = new JLabel();

                pieceLabel.setLocation(tileCoord.x, tileCoord.y);
                add(pieceLabel);

            }

            if( boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y] != null) {

                // Retrieves the first letter of the class name
                String pieceAbbrevation = boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y].getClass().getSimpleName().substring(0, 1);

                // Retrieves the team name: UP or DOWN
                String teamAbbreviation = boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y].getTeam().name();

                // Short name is Knight is actually N, but the String above will retrieve K instead.
                if(boardSetting[tileCoord.x][tileCoord.y].getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Knight")) {
                    pieceAbbrevation = "N";
                }

                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(pieceImagesPath + pieceAbbrevation + teamAbbreviation + ".png"));
                    JLabel pieceLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));


                    //pieceButton.setBackground(highlightColor);
                    pieceLabel.setLocation(tileCoord.x, tileCoord.y);
                    add(pieceLabel);



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have to re-trigger the `placePieceGraphic` method of your TileGUI

Comment: So, something like, board.movePieceTo(boardSetting, 4, 4, boardSetting[position.x][position.y]); placePieceGraphic(boardSetting); inside my mouseClicked, right? I just tried that but nothing happened. It seems valid though. Do you know any further steps that I have to take?

Comment: within `placePieceGraphic` you add a new Button or Graphic every time you call the method. So the previous one will still be there. You have to call `removeAll()` at the beginning of the method. And you can call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` in the end of the method to explicitly trigger a repaint of the panel.

Comment: Yeah that even sounds more valid, but still kinda doesn't work. Could you check my edited code?

Comment: do you also call `placePieceGraphic ` in your mosuelistener `repaint()` in the end of the method?

Comment: do I have to put repaint() inside the very end of the placePieceGraphic?

Comment: yes together with `revalidate()`

Comment: Okay. So I updated my edit. This is what happens so far. When I click the Pawn, it gives me a message "Pawn" (showMessageDialog in mouseClicked) and disappears (movePieceTo in mouseClicked). But it does not reappear on 4,4 which is the hardcoded position, although it seems like the Piece has moved to 4,4; it's just not re-drawing it properly. Do you see the problem in my new EDIT?

Comment: You have to call revalidate() before repaint()